# View feature space for multi-band files

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-plugins, remote-sensing, saga

I am trying to plot a feature space (scatter plot) for some SPOT images in QGIS 2.8.1. I know a histogram is available in the file properties, but I want to plot eg. Band 1 vs Band 2 to see the feature space.

The [SCP plug-in](http://fromgistors.blogspot.com/p/roidock.html)  has a function which only shows the scatter plot for the created ROI. What I am looking for is to show a scatter plot (feature space) of two full bands. And if possible, also show my ROI or signatures in the full scatter plot.

I am evaluating QGIS for GIS and RS introduction for our students. We consider the feature space as an important tool for the students to understand which landscape elements the different bands are good at identifying.

In ERDAS it would look something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly the answer to your question, but rather a suggestion. For RS, I would not use QGIS as a core software, because it is more oriented for GIS (even if it includes many tools). I suggest that you have a look at GRASS 7 (the new GUI is a true step forward). I don't have a look of experience because it is new, but I got some feedback and I've seen some demo which are really promising.

For the scatter plot, see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umNLISWzTlk). If I understand what you want to do, this is what you need. It makes use of the [interactive scatterplot tools](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/wxGUI.iscatt.html) (launched from the supervised classification tool)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Running GRASS could be an option, but I was hoping to find a plugin in QGIS which can do the same. That there currently is no such plugin is of course also an answer, though it was not what I hoped for :)

Comment: I don't think that there is a plugin, but I don't know QGIS good enough to be 100% sure. This is why I didn't put it like this in my answer.